# My code doesn't finds a table in Wikipedia

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the last table (titled "Registro de los casos") on [this wikipedia page](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Argentina#Cronolog%C3%ADa)

with this python 3.7 code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

def webcrawler():

    url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Argentina"#Cronolog%C3%ADa"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")
    tables = soup.findAll("table", class_='wikitable')[0]
    #print(tables)

    for table in tables:
        if isinstance(table, NavigableString):
            continue
        ths = table.find_all('th')
        headings = [th.text.strip() for th in ths]
        print(headings)


webcrawler()
```

But it only finds the first table, and not the last. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you set `tables` to the first item that is returned by `soup.findAll("table", class_='wikitable')[0]`. If you take out `[0]` you write all tables with that class to the `tables` variable

Comment: @Beek I'm so dumb! Write it as answer, and I mark it as answer.

Comment: happens sometimes, wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `tables` to the first item that is returned by `soup.findAll("table", class_='wikitable')[0]`. If you take out `[0]` you write all tables with that class to the tables variable